# cURL takes the different time than the browser

Tags: php, php-curl

I have to get a date value from an HTML page and I am getting the HTML code with cURL in this way

PHP

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $website_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_errno($curl) ? '1' : '0';
curl_close($curl);
```

If I display the page with my browser, the date value is (13 nov 2021 ore 10.30) while if you get it with cURL the value given 9h less (13 nov 2021 ore 1.30).
I tried to insert this option in cURL

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9']);
```

And this seems to work as it shows the voice 'ORA' in Italian, but the time differs by 9h.

I also tried to insert this on my curl php page but without success.

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT.UTF-8'); ?>
```

EDIT - I am trying to recover the date from the Steamworshop page where there are the addon who are released.

Example page

[image]

How could I do? Thanks

Comment: `the date value`...what date value? What HTML? Since we can't see what you're referring to, and we don't know anything about the remote page or how it decides what to display, there's very little we can do to help you other than guess, which generally isn't productive.

Comment: @ADyson - I'm sorry, you're right, I edited my question.

Comment: We still don't know how that site decides what date/time to display, though.

Comment: Why not take a look at the header sent from your browser?

Comment: It is possible that the remote page has the date display populated via Javascript

Comment: @shingo - I hadn't thought about this. Thanks